# How ToList() is working here?

Tags: c#, linq

This might be rather trivial but I am unable to understand this from sometime. I need to remove some items from a collection. I have a list of my model which is filled from database. I further extracted different collections from that list and then tried to remove some items but it didn't work in the way I thought it to be

```
List<MyModel> temp = DbHelper.Select("Tree"); // count of temp is 40
var _doc = temp.Where(x => x.Parent == code + "02"); // count of _doc is 9
// type of _doc is System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator<MyModel>
var cd = _doc.ToList().RemoveAll(x => x.S7 == "CDFL"); // cd is 2
```

Since cd has value 2 so, 2 items should be removed from _doc. But _doc has still 9 items in it.

But then I changed the type of _doc to list as follows:

```
var _doc = temp.Where(x => x.Parent == code + "02").ToList(); // count of _doc is 9
// type of _doc is List<MyModel>
var cd = _doc.RemoveAll(x => x.S7 == "CDFL"); // cd is 2
```

And the count of _doc is 7 which is correct.

The RemoveAll is being called on a type of List in both cases so, why the behavior is different in both?

Comment: In the first case you have got a query in `_doc`. Yes it is enumerable but it is essentially just a query, not an in-memory collection. In the second case you got a concrete in-memory structure in `_doc`. In the second case you are removing from it. In the first case you are removing from `_doc.ToList()` to which you got no handle/variable that points to the exact reference in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This following line of code

```
var _doc = temp.Where(x => x.Parent == code + "02").ToList();
```

creates a **new list** from the items of `temp` that passed the filtered.

Then at the following line

```
var cd = _doc.RemoveAll(x => x.S7 == "CDFL");
```

You remove those items from **this** list, the resulted form the `ToList`.

Whereas in the following line

```
var _doc = temp.Where(x => x.Parent == code + "02");
```

you **just define** a linq query and you don't force to be executed. The type of `_doc` now is a `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is the type of `x`. In order to see which items pass this filter you have to force it to be executed. This can be done with **many ways**. Some of them are the following

- By looping through this sequence using a `foreach` statement.
- By calling `ToList`
- By calling `ToArray`

Now the critical point is in the following line:

```
var cd = _doc.ToList().RemoveAll(x => x.S7 == "CDFL");
```

Let's take it piece by piece. As I mentioned above `_doc.ToList()` would create  a new `Lit<T>`. Then you apply the `RemoveAll` on this list.

**That's the difference**. The `_doc` would have the same reference as it had before you called the `ToList`. Furthermore, the `RemoveAll` would have been applied to the list that has been created from the call of `ToList`.

[Query Execution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738633(v=vs.110).aspx) at this link you would find more info and you would read about two very common terms in situations like this, *deferred query execution* and *immediate query exeqution*.

Comment: Excellent explanation, THANKS

Answer (score 1):

According to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The ToList(IEnumerable) method forces immediate
>   query evaluation and returns a List that contains the query
>   results. You can append this method to your query in order to obtain a
>   cached copy of the query results.

So, in the first case you're removing items from new instance of List and that's the reason why these elements aren't removed from _doc collection.